# Querying hierarchical data with T-SQL getting some aggregated data

Tags: sql, parent-child, common-table-expression, hierarchy

I need to query some parent-child tree data in a single table. The structure of this table is defined by a customers database and cannot be changed.

The result we try to achieve is that we get one result row per table row with the rows data itself plus the path from to to row itself in a display friendly way.

Additionally the Top Most Parent that was used in the hierarchy (see row 8 as an example for an orphaned row, parent does not exist anymore, which can totally be the case at this customers database, as this will not render the data invalid in his use cases) and the most restrictive validity dates in the hierarchy (so the max ValidFrom and min ValidTo, NULL represents no restriction in Validity).

The table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HiTest]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ValidFrom] [datetime] NULL,
    [ValidTo] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_HiTest] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And the test data:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[HiTest] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[HiTest] ([Id], [ParentId], [Name], [ValidFrom], [ValidTo]) 
VALUES (1, NULL, N'First Level', NULL, NULL),
       (2, 1, N'Second Level 1', CAST(N'2022-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (3, 1, N'Second Level 2', NULL, NULL),
       (4, 2, N'Third Level 1', CAST(N'2022-02-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2022-12-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (5, 3, N'Third Level 2', CAST(N'2022-03-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2022-10-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (6, 4, N'Fourth Level 1a', CAST(N'2022-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2022-09-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (6, 4, N'Fourth Level 1a', CAST(N'2022-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2022-09-30T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime)),
       (8, 23, N'Orphaned Level', NULL, NULL)
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[HiTest] OFF
```

And the expected result should be:

[image: Expected Result]

Can you hint me to the best solution for this scenario (a performant way, there are round about 120000 data rows in this table). At moment, I am playing around with an CTE solution, but I am not getting it to work.

Thank you in advance.
SR

Comment: CTE is possibly the simplest way, what version RDBMS? Later version have some new tricks, but post your CTE, you might just be missing something simple.

Comment: Often the act of posting your code and trying to justify the decisions you made lead to you finding the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CTE is going to be the simplest option, given that you have multiple cascading rules that are not simple *COALESCE* scenarios, that is it not simple nullability checking. Judging by your output, the `Agg Valid...` range can only be *more restrictive* than the parent range, so if the *parent* is valid from **April** to **August** of the same year, then the *child* cannot be valid before **April**, or after **August**. It can however be made valid from **May** to **July** as this is a more restrictive range than the parent.

Outside of the standard Hierarchy CTE logic the following conditions need to be tracked:

- Keep a reference to the original parent record's `[ParentId]`, pass this through *unchanged*.
- `[Path]` is either the current `[Id]` if `[ParentId]` is NULL, if there is *no existing parent record* but there is a `[ParentId]` value, then construct the path from the `[ParentId]\[Id]`. Otherwise *append* the *parent* `[Path]` with a '\' and the *child* `[Id]`
- `[ValidFrom]` *COALESCE* from the *Parent* (first _non-null) value

  - can be overridden if the *child* is greater than the *parent*
- `[ValidTo]` *COALESCE* from the *Parent* (first _non-null) value

  - can be overridden if the child is *less* than the *parent*

At the end of the Recursive CTE, we join back onto the main table to pickup the additional fields to display with the current record:

```
WITH Hierarchy AS (
  SELECT [Id], [ParentId] -- < standard Hierarchy requirements
       , [ParentId] AS [Master]
       , [Path] = ISNULL(CAST([ParentId] AS VARCHAR(max)) + '\' + CAST([Id] AS VARCHAR(max)), CAST([Id] AS VARCHAR(max)))
       , [ValidFrom], [ValidTo]
  FROM [HiTest]
  WHERE [ParentId] IS NULL OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [HiTest] lookup WHERE lookup.[id] = [HiTest].[ParentId])
  
  UNION ALL

  SELECT [child].[Id], [child].[ParentId]
       , [parent].[Master] --> don't change this value
       , CONCAT([parent].[Path], '\', CAST([child].[Id] AS VARCHAR(max))) AS [Path]
       , CASE 
             WHEN [parent].[ValidFrom] IS NULL THEN [child].[ValidFrom]
             WHEN [child].[ValidFrom] > [parent].[ValidFrom] THEN [child].[ValidFrom]
             ELSE [parent].[ValidFrom]
         END
       , CASE 
             WHEN [parent].[ValidTo] IS NULL THEN [child].[ValidTo]
             WHEN [child].[ValidTo] < [parent].[ValidTo] THEN [child].[ValidTo]
             ELSE [parent].[ValidTo]
         END
  FROM [HiTest] [child]
  INNER JOIN Hierarchy parent ON [child].[ParentId] = [parent].[Id]
)
SELECT [HiTest].[Id], [HiTest].[ParentId], [Name], [HiTest].[ValidFrom], [HiTest].[ValidTo], [Path]
  , [Hierarchy].[ValidFrom] AS [Agg. ValidFrom]
  , [Hierarchy].[ValidTo] AS [Agg. ValidTo]
  , [Master] AS [Top Most Parent Id]
FROM [Hierarchy]
INNER JOIN [HiTest] ON [Hierarchy].[Id] = [HiTest].[Id]
ORDER BY [Id]
```

View this fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/5M6QLC8w

Usually we wouldn't sort a list like this by the child item Id (*leaf*), it would be more common to `ORDER BY [Path]` (*branch*) to visualize the Hierarchy:

| Id | ParentId | Name | ValidFrom | ValidTo | Path | Agg. ValidFrom | Agg. ValidTo | Top Most Parent Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | First Level | null | null | 1 | null | null | null |
| 2 | 1 | Second Level 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 | 1\2 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 | null |
| 4 | 2 | Third Level 1 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-12-31 | 1\2\4 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-12-31 | null |
| 6 | 4 | Fourth Level 1a | 2022-01-01 | 2022-09-30 | 1\2\4\6 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-09-30 | null |
| 7 | 4 | Fourth Level 1b | null | null | 1\2\4\7 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-12-31 | null |
| 3 | 1 | Second Level 2 | null | null | 1\3 | null | null | null |
| 5 | 3 | Third Level 2 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-10-31 | 1\3\5 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-10-31 | null |
| 8 | 23 | Orphaned Level | 2011-01-01 | 2012-12-31 | 23\8 | 2011-01-01 | 2012-12-31 | 23 |

Comment: Thank you Chris,
as far as I can see, your solution is already the perfect solution for my problem. We are on MS SQL 15.0.2***. In my original cte I struggled with the orphaned row (as I just did not realize how to handle that) and the "Aggregated" Min Max ValidFrom / ValidTo. I just did not think about this way. Yeah, sometimes you just need another point of view.

Comment: Yes having analyzed this for a day now, it really is a usefull solution. I am wondering now if it can be tweaked in a way, I can put this in a function or better a view and also if it is possible to change the query in such a way, that it does not do the recursive querying for the whole table, but just the lines I need, for example, if I put it in a view and query the view with a Condition of where ID in (5, 6, 7)? As we need to somehow get this to work with entity framework where we need to join those with another table (that join would already reduce the amount of lines we need to calcualte)

Comment: @sraux you can certainly add filters inside (or before) the recursive query and in many cases it is a good idea to do so, but you can't just filter by specific Id's with the current query because it builds form the parent root. If you filtered by `ID IN (5,6,7)` then you would not pickup any of the other _parent_ information for the records that match these `ID` values. Is _by `ID`_ the primary way you would want to filter? It will require the recursive query to traverse the hierarchy from the leaf, not the root.